# Hide "Store" and other apps from Remote Desktop (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I'm setting up a new Windows Server 2012 for Remote Desktop users.

How can I hide the "Store" app (and other apps) from the users?

Thanks!

Mojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be mamaged through Group Policy in Server 2012

IT Administrators can turn access to the Windows Store on or off in the following ways:
• For specific machines
• For specific users and groups

[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh832040.aspx#BKMK_TurnOnOff) has more info regarding this.  This is one section

Comment: Thanks! I was Looking in the wrong place "Local Security Policy" - found it in the local "Group policy". :) thanks again